# Change Policy of Microsoft Edge with JSON

Tags: docker, group-policy, microsoft-edge

I'm used to changing Policy in Chrome by adding the *.json* file to `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed` in Linux

I'm trying to apply the same to Edge as I'm seeing some policies are no more available in Chrome but they are on Edge (UserDataDir for instance)

Because I'm planning to change it on a Docker Container, I can't access the Windows Group Policy Editor or the Windows Registry as explained in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-manage-extensions-ref-guide)

So, I'm trying to understand if there was another method involving the add of a .json file (or some other files) to change it

Comment: No; On Windows the group policy or the respective registry key is it

Comment: How are the Docker image/container and Edge related? Are we talking about a Windows or a Linux container/image?

Comment: @DanielB a Linux one https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-edge

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re going to be running Edge in a Linux Docker container, you need to use the “Linux way” to add policies.

According to [this conversation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/global-profile-configuration-on-linux/m-p/2365884), that works pretty much like it does with Chrome. Put your policies in `/etc/opt/edge/policies/managed`, done.

You can either use a volume mount to add these files to a Docker container or you can create your own Docker image derived from `selenium/standalone-edge`, with the policies added. It could look like this:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-edge:110.0

ADD my-policy.json /etc/opt/edge/policies/managed/
```

---

Note that I have not actually tested this.